# Use AJAX and jQuery with WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get [this W3 Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax) to work in WordPress.

I already tried this in function.php:

```
function hook_ajax_script(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_script', get_bloginfo('template_url')."/rscripts/robajax.js" );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hook_ajax_script' );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hook_ajax_script' );

add_shortcode( 'ajax1', 'ajax1_shortcode' );
    function ajax1_shortcode( $args ) {
    ?>
    <div id="demo">
    <h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
    </div>
```

and my Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("button").click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({url: "rob.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

When I click the Button I get 404 "rob.txt" not found.

I tried it also to do it with a Plugin and rob.txt was inside.

How to get this example to work?

Comment: Since you're not passing an absolute URL, your script will try to load a file called `rob.txt` located at the root of the current page (eg. `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=your-custom-admin-page` or `http://www.example.com/page-with-short-code/`) and of course it won't find it, hence the 404 error message.

Comment: Oh Sorry, i edit the post.... i post the wronge code. tried to much ...:-)

Comment: What I said above still applies, though.

Comment: You're missing many important parts. The duplicate questions should give you a better start. It's important to check the guides [ask] and [mcve] before posting questions here. Good luck!